# Sencha Touch Vertical Scroll Issue

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

I have a list with a button at the bottom, you only see the button if you scroll to the bottom.  When I turn my phone landscape mode it allows me to scroll but not with it is in portrait mode.  I can't figure out why I can scroll in one view but not the other??

here is my config code:

```
var config = {
        cls: 'customizationScreen',
        titlebarTitle: 'Customize',
        scroll: 'vertical',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
            },
        items: [
            {
                scroll: 'vertical',
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [this.customizationList]
            },
            {
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'center',
                    pack: 'center'
                    },
                defaults: {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        baseCls: 'greyButtonUp orderButton',
                        pressedCls: 'greyButtonDown'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Check-Out',
                        handler: Ext.createDelegate(this.onCheckOutClick, this)
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

    };
```

Any suggestions, thanks so much?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't gotten a chance to try this out these
1. Add layout:'fit'

```
items: [
        {
            scroll: 'vertical',
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [this.customizationList]
        },
```

If that didn't work I would use a DataView instead of a List and see if that works.

I'm basing this on similar (but different) issue I read about here.

[Sencha forums post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?124345-list-behind-dockedItems-and-not-scrolling-in-TabPanel)

If you figure this out let us know...

Comment: When I added "layout: 'fit'" to my code it just squashed all the components together onto the screen, a few components were even missing.